# reversing a string in python without using methods or slicing

Tags: python, debugging

This function tries to reverse a provided string.

```
z=[]
x=range(10)
def reve(y):
    for i in range(len(y)):
        z.append(y[len-1-i])
    return z
print reve(x)
```

This is the error I got.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/second pyth", line 40, in ?
    print reve(x)
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/second pyth", line 38, in reve
    z.append(y[len-1-i])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'`

Cant understand. Solution anybody?

Comment: `z.append(y[len(y)-1-i])` is what is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks.. that was stupid .. sorry guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the length the ietarable ie, `y`.

```
z.append(y[len(y)-1-i])
```

Code:

```
z=[]
x=range(10)
def reve(y):
    for i in range(len(y)):
        z.append(y[len(y)-1-i])
    return z
print reve(x)
```

Output:

```
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def rev(s):
    s1=""
    s2=""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i]!=" " and i!=len(s)-1:
            s1+=s[i]
        elif s[i]==" ":
            s2+=s1[::-1]+" "
            s1=""
        else:
            s1+=s[i]
            s2+=s1[::-1]
    return s2
if__name__="__main__"
s=input("Enter a sentense : ")
print("Sentence with individual reverse word : ",rev(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s1 = 'foo'
>>> s2 = ''
>>> for i in range(len(s1)):
        s2 += s1[len(s1)-i-1]


>>> s2
'oof'
```

Of course this is much less efficient than:

```
>>> s1[::-1]
'oof'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Reversing a string without using s[::-1]
str = "ecnalubma"
count = -8
while count <= 0:
    print(str[-count], end='')
    count += 1
```

Comment: The user is asking for help debugging a specific piece of code, and the code you provided has no relationship with the code in the question.